# How to correctly count a word, newline, and character in C

Tags: c, file, word-count

For a homework assignment, I'm implementing a recursive version of `wc` on linux. The format of this looks like this:

`new_line_count    word_count    character_count file_name`

I haven't had issues traversing, and grabbing each file from a directory, or any issues actually reading a file in. My problem comes when trying to correctly count the words, characters and new lines.

To count these things, I created three global variables (that reset after an entire file is read), and then used a switch statement to count everything:

```
#define SPACE 32
#define NEW_LINE 10
#define VERT_TAB 11
#define C_RETURN 13

unsigned int new_line = 0;
unsigned int word_count = 0;
unsigned int char_count = 0;

void check_wc(int i, char *file_name)
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case SPACE:
            char_count++;
            word_count++;
            break;
        case NEW_LINE:
        case VERT_TAB:
        case C_RETURN:
            char_count++;
            word_count++;
            new_line++;
            break;
        default:
            char_count++;
    }
}
```

My results match up with wc's results when running it on simple text files. The problem comes when I run my program on `my_wc.c`.

This is `wc`'s results:

```
 204     471    4034 my_wc.c
```

And these are my results:

```
 204    1100    4034 my_wc.c
```

As you can see, the word count is way off.. probably because a space is considered a word when doing a newline. However, when I tried to build something like a finite state machine that checks special conditions like that, my character count, newline count, and word count still ends up wrong.

Is there something glaringly obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you accounting for multiple white space occurrences "      word      " is still only 1 word but would come out as many with your algorithm.

Comment: You're counting every whitespace character as a new word. A word is a transition from a non-whitespace character to a whitespace character so you need to remember if the previous character was whitespace or not.

Comment: If I only give you the character `f` in isolation, you cannot possibly tell whether it means a new word has begun or not.  You'll need to store [some context](https://xkcd.com/1090/).

Comment: In addition to what everyone else said, you seem to have forgotten the horizontal `TAB` character. And it's debatable as to whether a carriage-return should be included in the line count (but that's mainly an issue on Microsoft OS's).

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you need to keep track of whether you are inside a word or not:

```
characters = 0
words = 0
newlines = 0
in_word = false

foreach character c in file
  characters++

  if c == '\n'
    newlines++

  if isspace (c) // includes newlines
    in_word = false
  else
    if (!in_word)
      in_word = true
      words++
```